# Galois extension of exponent $mp^r$ in characteristic $p$

Tags: galois-theory, positive-characteristic, galois-cohomology, kummer-theory

Kummer theory treats Galois extensions of exponents that are not divisible by the characteristic. Artin-Schreier and Witt extend this theory for Galois extensions of exponents $p^r$ in characteristic $p$ ($p$ prime, $r \in \mathbb{N}$).

Is there any theory that extends/combines this theory to Galois extensions of exponent $p^r m$, where $m$ is not divided by $p$?

From chapter 10 of Bosch's book "Algebra" I know that general Kummer theory can be applied to Galois groups $G$ if there exist a continous $G$-module $A$
and a surjective $G$-homomorphism $\phi: A \rightarrow A$ with certain properties. For Galois extensions of exponent $p^r m$ Witt rings are used to define $A$. Is there something similar for extensions of exponent $p^r m$?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't both Kummer and Artin-Schreier+Witt deal with **abelian** extensions only? If you are also interested in abelian extensions only then you can write any abelian group of order $p^rm$ as a direct product of subgroups of respective orders $p^r$ and $m$. Then you can apply whichever theory that fits and do a composition, no?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment - this is really helpful, I didn't think about it. Do you know if a group can be written as a suitable direct sum and the composition works even if it is not finitely generated (and though every element vanishes by the exponent $p^r m$)?